# Backbone. Model attributes gets undefined on Model.save();

Tags: backbone.js

Im trying to save a model after my attributes gets set. But when i look in the console i see that all attributes gets undefined. Anyone here that can help me on this?

This is my model:

```
PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 

url: "api/?action=answerQuestion&question_id="+this.questionId+"&option_id="+this.optionId+"&type="+this.role,

defaults: {
    questionId: 0,
    optionId: 0,
    role: 0
},

initialize: function(){

}
```

});

And here is the function where i want to save/post it.

```
        answerQuestion: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('li').each(function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('inactive');
    });
    $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

    var currentQuestion = 1;
    var answer = parseInt($(event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('data-answer'));
    var role = 1;

    var postModel = new PostModel();
    postModel.set({ 
        questionId: currentQuestion, 
        optionId: answer, 
        role: role
    });

    postModel.save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `this.questionId` to get model attributes in Backbone; use [`this.get('questionId')`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) instead.

That's part of the problem, but you'll still end up with empty values in your `url` property if you simply update your definition to use `this.get()` instead. If you set `url` to be a string it's when your model is defined - **not** when you create a model, and it won't be updated when your data changes.

Fortunately, [Backbone lets you define `url` as a function too](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url), which will do what you expect:

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    url: function() { 
        return "/api?action=answerQuestion" + 
            "&question_id=" + this.get('questionId') + 
            "&option_id=" + this.get('optionId') + 
            "&type=" + this.get('role');
    },  

    defaults: {
        questionId: 0,
        optionId: 0,
        role: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats seems to work good! I have one question tho. When i now runt it and look in the console i now get one "post" and one "get" request. Should it be like that? i only want to post it.

Comment: `Model.save()` should only make a POST request. I'd suspect something happening elsewhere in your code is triggering that GET.

Comment: Yea, probaly. Thing is tho that this is basically all the application do so far. On a click event the *answerQuestion* runs, picks the data-attribute and inits the Model.

Comment: Ah! It's a `click` event on a link, right? That's probably where your GET is coming from. Whack an [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) into your click handler and you should be good to go.

Comment: I was actually thinking the same thing and tried that. No luck unfortunately.

Comment: I have now edited my post and added the full click function. answerQuestion.

Comment: I think it would be best to make a new post for the POST/GET problem, as it's unrelated to the original question. 

NB. jQuery's `.each()` function takes a callback in the form `function(i, el)` so you should update your loop over the `<li>` elements to reflect that.